# Film grain in text effect - Premiere Pro

Tags: premiere

The effect I am trying to achieve has film grain inside colored texts. I was able to somewhat recreate it using Track Matte Key. But I can't get the color part to work.

Thanks!

Sample:

[image]
Mine:

[image]

Comment: Do you have a link to a video version of what you're trying to achieve? It's pretty hard to tell from a still.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kAJx1TaDj3w

Here! Any of the "PART" title cards

Answer (score 0):

That looks more like coloured noise and less like grain to me.  To make something similar:

[image]

The font looks to be Acuta Fat according to whatthefont.com
https://www.myfonts.com/products/fat-acuta-medium-110325

Add your text to a layer and put it on track V2.

Create a Colour Matte, choose a pinky red colour, and add it to track V1.

[image]

Add the Noise effect to the colour matte, and raise the amount of noise to 92% or so.  Make sure "Use Colour Noise" is selected.

Add a Track Matte Key effect to your colour matte clip on track V1.
For the Matte setting, make sure it is set to track V2.
Composite using Matte Alpha

Scale up the clip on V1 slightly to make the grain bigger.